# What is the easiest way to set up a cron job?

Tags: software-recommendation, cron

Every time I set up a cron job there is something wrong with it and I spend a lot of time trouble shooting it.

I use Ubuntu and I would like to know what tools exist to make my life easier when setting up cron.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install `Scheduled Tasks`:

[image]

Add a job to it and set it up the way you like. It will be added to your cron table.

[image]